# How to forecast future dataframe using sklearn python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, forecasting, sklearn-pandas

I am running the example from [this](https://pythonprogramming.net/forecasting-predicting-machine-learning-tutorial/) link.

I have successfully ran the code after few modifications. Here is the code modified:

```
import quandl, math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing, cross_validation, svm
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import datetime

style.use('ggplot')

df = quandl.get("WIKI/GOOGL")
df = df[['Adj. Open',  'Adj. High',  'Adj. Low',  'Adj. Close', 'Adj. Volume']]
df['HL_PCT'] = (df['Adj. High'] - df['Adj. Low']) / df['Adj. Close'] * 100.0
df['PCT_change'] = (df['Adj. Close'] - df['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. Open'] * 100.0

df = df[['Adj. Close', 'HL_PCT', 'PCT_change', 'Adj. Volume']]
forecast_col = 'Adj. Close'
df.fillna(value=-99999, inplace=True)
forecast_out = int(math.ceil(0.01 * len(df)))
df['label'] = df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out)

X = np.array(df.drop(['label'], 1))
X = preprocessing.scale(X)
X_lately = X[-forecast_out:]
X = X[:-forecast_out]

df.dropna(inplace=True)

y = np.array(df['label'])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
clf = LinearRegression(n_jobs=-1)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
confidence = clf.score(X_test, y_test)

forecast_set = clf.predict(X_lately)
df['Forecast'] = np.nan

last_date = df.iloc[-1].name
last_unix = last_date.timestamp()
one_day = 86400
next_unix = last_unix + one_day

for i in forecast_set:
    next_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(next_unix)
    next_unix += 86400
    df.loc[next_date] = [np.nan for _ in range(len(df.columns)-1)]+[i]

df['Adj. Close'].plot()
df['Forecast'].plot()
plt.legend(loc=4)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.show()
```

But the issue I am facing is with the forecasting of the future dataframe. Here is the output image:

[image: image output]

I am getting till 2017-2018 as in the image. How to move further to 2019, 2020 or 5 years from now?

Answer (score 7):

Your code uses this DataFrame as the `X` to generate predictions:

```
df = df[['Adj. Close', 'HL_PCT', 'PCT_change', 'Adj. Volume']]
```

This means that if you want to predict prices five years into the future you would need these `['Adj. Close', 'HL_PCT', 'PCT_change', 'Adj. Volume']` data points for future values to keep predicting further away.

Notice that the forecast in your image was created from historical data that was separated as a test set here: `X_lately = X[-forecast_out:]`. So every point it has a prediction uses historical data to predict some point in the future.

If you really want to use this model to forecast 5 years in the future you would first need to forecast/calculate all these variables: `predicted_X = ['Adj. Close', 'HL_PCT', 'PCT_change', 'Adj. Volume']`, and keep running some loop with `clf.predict(predicted_X)` inside.

I believe this [Machine Learning Course for Trading at Udacity](https://br.udacity.com/course/machine-learning-for-trading--ud501) might be a good resource for you and it will give you a better framework and mindset to tackle this kind of problem.

I hope that my answer is clear and helpful for you, if it is not just let me know and I will clarify it or answer other issues.

**Follows your model updated with what I said:**

```
import quandl
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing, model_selection
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import datetime

style.use('ggplot')

df = quandl.get("WIKI/GOOGL")
df = df[['Adj. Open', 'Adj. High', 'Adj. Low', 'Adj. Close', 'Adj. Volume']]
df['HL_PCT'] = (df['Adj. High'] - df['Adj. Low']) / df['Adj. Close'] * 100.0
df['PCT_change'] = (df['Adj. Close'] - df['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. Open'] * 100.0

df = df[['Adj. Close', 'HL_PCT', 'PCT_change', 'Adj. Volume']]
forecast_col = 'Adj. Close'
df.fillna(value=-99999, inplace=True)
forecast_out = 1
df['label'] = df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out)

X = np.array(df.drop(['label'], 1))
X = preprocessing.scale(X)
X_lately = X[-forecast_out:]
X = X[:-forecast_out]

df.dropna(inplace=True)

y = np.array(df['label'])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

# Instantiate regressors
reg_close = LinearRegression(n_jobs=-1)
reg_close.fit(X_train, y_train)

reg_hl = LinearRegression(n_jobs=-1)
reg_hl.fit(X_train, y_train)

reg_pct = LinearRegression(n_jobs=-1)
reg_pct.fit(X_train, y_train)

reg_vol = LinearRegression(n_jobs=-1)
reg_vol.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Prepare variables for loop
last_close = df['Adj. Close'][-1]
last_date = df.iloc[-1].name.timestamp()
df['Forecast'] = np.nan
predictions_arr = X_lately

for i in range(100):
    # Predict next point in time
    last_close_prediction = reg_close.predict(predictions_arr)
    last_hl_prediction = reg_hl.predict(predictions_arr)
    last_pct_prediction = reg_pct.predict(predictions_arr)
    last_vol_prediction = reg_vol.predict(predictions_arr)

    # Create np.Array of current predictions to serve as input for future predictions
    predictions_arr = np.array((last_close_prediction, last_hl_prediction, last_pct_prediction, last_vol_prediction)).T
    next_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(last_date)
    last_date += 86400

    # Outputs data into DataFrame to enable plotting
    df.loc[next_date] = [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, float(last_close_prediction)]

df['Adj. Close'].plot()
df['Forecast'].plot()
plt.legend(loc=4)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.show()
```

This model is not very useful as it very quickly explodes upwards, but there are some interesting and unusual things in its implementation.

To get a more realistic prediction of future prices you would need to implement some kind of random walk as well.

You could also use different models instead of the `LinearRegression` such as `RandomForestRegressor`, which yields very different results.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

clf_close = RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs=-1)
clf_close.fit(X_train, y_train)

clf_hl = RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs=-1)
clf_hl.fit(X_train, y_train)

clf_pct = RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs=-1)
clf_pct.fit(X_train, y_train)

clf_vol = RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs=-1)
clf_vol.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Instead of predicting prices, it is usually a much better approach to predict whether or not a specific position (buy or sell) is profitable given certain entry parameters and exit parameters. The [Udacity course](https://br.udacity.com/course/machine-learning-for-trading--ud501) covers this approach.

**Random Walk model:**

```
import quandl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import datetime
import random

style.use('ggplot')

df = quandl.get("WIKI/GOOGL")
df = df[['Adj. Close']]

df.dropna(inplace=True)

# Prepare variables for loop

last_close = df['Adj. Close'][-1]
last_date = df.iloc[-1].name.timestamp()
df['Forecast'] = np.nan

for i in range(1000):
    # Create np.Array of current predictions to serve as input for future predictions
    modifier = random.randint(-100, 105) / 10000 + 1
    last_close *= modifier
    next_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(last_date)
    last_date += 86400

    # Outputs data into DataFrame to enable plotting
    df.loc[next_date] = [np.nan, last_close]

df['Adj. Close'].plot()
df['Forecast'].plot()
plt.legend(loc=4)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.show()
```

**Output Image from Random Walk**

[image: Random Walk Graph]

Comment: It is a bit helpful. I am trying to make it out with the answer you have given and the reference, If not then I will surely ask for help and I hope you would help me.

Comment: I am not able to understand the concept properly.. I guess due to financial terminology. Can you please help me by making the necessary improvements in my code,please?

Comment: @Jaffer, I've posted the necessary improvements in your code as requested. I'll comment it out later. In case you have any doubts, let me know that I'll address them.

Comment: Sorry but the solution not working for me... Here I have posted the jupyter notebook. You can check it yourself what is the issue. I program is not forecasting properly as the graph is linear throughout and no up and downs:  https://github.com/JafferWilson/test/blob/master/CodeForcast.ipynb  Using both the logic.. please help me.

Comment: @Jaffer, the code in your jupyter notebook is working as it should. The issue is that these Linear Regression models are really poor to do the job, specially when you use them to estimate the input variables as well. It is really important to have some kind of Random Walk to make those models work better. But even that, it might be a lot of work put into to something that will not have much predictive power. Anyways, I made a Random Walk model for you, and added to my answer, so you can get a better idea of what I am talking about.

Comment: @Jaffer. you could do both a Random Walk and a Linear Regression (or other machine learning algorithms) at the same time if you want to. It will look more like the real thing, but I would be surprised if it had any predictive power to be honest.

Comment: I am still not getting the output as your image. See what I got after running your code: https://ibb.co/kQWnax   
https://ibb.co/kRH4Nc  Kindly check the images. I am getting 0's in the forecast.... Please let me know Am I missing something?

Comment: I  guess because of the random numbers.

Comment: @Jaffer can you post the link to a notebook? That should be working.

Comment: @Jaffer I won't have access to a computer for the next 10 hours or so, but the code below 'Random Walk'  was everything I used to built that graph. There could be a typo or something, but copying and pasting if should work. Otherwise just do some basic debugging to check why the forecast column = 0, that is not a possible expected result if the code runs correctly. As there is no seed for random number, the graph will look very different every time.

Comment: Yes I did the debugging and what I got is the Random function is the culprit. ` modifier = random.randint(-100, 105) / 10000 + 1` is the line that is not letting the graph go random but a straight line. The values obtained are 0 or 1 and not other value. I tried to change it but I don't know why  am not getting a graph like you. This is may be the environment you are running have some different number in buffer whereas mine has no random numbers yet.. What I guess ....!

Comment: @Jaffer, that is really weird. Don't get it why random would show different behaviors. Maybe you can try to run it on a different interpreter, I am using Python 3.6.4. I've made a notebook as well: https://github.com/joaoavf/misc/blob/master/stackoverflow/forecast.ipynb

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.... But I dont think that would be a problem.. I will try using python 3.5 or 3.6

Answer (score 1):

1. Use all data to estimate the model (so no training and test set)
2. Forecast the T+1 moment with the estimated model.
3. Plug the T+1 moment back in the data
4. Go back to 1 until you've reached 5 years ahead.

or better, learn time-series statistics.

Comment: can you edit the code so that I can understand, please?

Comment: It can't be edited, because it is not a forecast algorithm. The code first cuts of 10% of the most recent observations. Then it estimates a model with 80% of the remaining observations. It uses 20% for validation, but in my eyes this is just loss of information. Next up, it plugs the first 10% of the observations in the estimated model and forecast a kind of one day ahead for each of these observations. But as you already have data for all these point, it essentially only forecast one day in the future in total. Google on rolling window, time series and python and you will find better algoritm

Comment: Can you help me modify the code to forecast? I know that the code  takes 10% as the test data and rest as training data..... Please let me know whether you can help me in that.